# AFNetworking adding quotes to JSON response keys

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, afnetworking

I have a weird error I can't wrap my head around.
I'm building an app that uses a remote JSON API to comunicate with.
I'm using AFNetworking to do the requests and run into a problem related to serializing the response.

When I make a call to our server using a browser i get a correct json response:

```
{
    {
            "tip_uuid": "4067d78c-a222-4190-8d5b-a6822a38e5e6",
            "deck_uuid": "c3c0854e-1f28-45ea-a643-c253b5c66a45",
            "user_uuid": "fb1dff53-b97f-47f3-b4e7-6c2184b85466",
            "latitude": "52.66",
            "longitude": "4",
            "categoryName": "Other",
            "imageURL": "\/images\/dummy_300.png",
            "averageRating": 3,
            "distanceToLocation": "7596772",
            "isUserAwesome": true
        }, 
       ..... (100 more responses)
 }
```

But when I make this same call using AFNetworking

[edited]

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager]; 
manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer]; 
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"ACCEPT"]; 
[manager POST:URLString parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) { 
    [self processServerResponse:responseObject successBlock:success failureBlock:failure]; 
}failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
          DLog(@"------- Failed url: %@ AFNetworking operation: %@. Responsestring: %@", URLString, [error description], operation.responseString);
          showM2(NSLocalizedString(@"Network error", @"Network error title"), NSLocalizedString(@"Please try again later", @"network error message"));
          failure(nil);
      }];
```

I get the response:
[/edited]

```
{
     {         
        averageRating = 0;
        categoryName = Music;
        "deck_uuid" = "c3c0854e-1f28-45ea-a643-c253b5c66a45";
        distanceToLocation = 5718;
        imageURL = "/images/tip/fb1dff53-b97f-47f3-b4e7-6c2184b85466_4dd49562817bc39f7567321c22469e7bf846f902_1389202937.png";
        isUserAwesome = 0;
        latitude = "52.3664193";
        longitude = "4.8871613";
        "tip_uuid" = "83d5a3f7-be60-4974-9347-67cadc307790";
        "user_uuid" = "fb1dff53-b97f-47f3-b4e7-6c2184b85466";
    },
    ....(100 more responses)
}
```

The (biggest) issue is that it somehow adds quotes around a couple of keys (tip_uuid, user_uuid and deck_uuid)

How come, and how can I fix this?

Comment: The code I'm using to make the request is:  AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"ACCEPT"];
    [manager POST:URLString parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        [self processServerResponse:responseObject successBlock:success failureBlock:failure];
    }

Comment: Instead of posting unreadable code in a comment, update your question with the code and delete the comment.

Comment: Sry mate, you are totally right, kinda new here,.. didn't see the "edit" button ;(

Comment: You're seeing the difference between JSON and an NSLog of an NSDictionary.  The NSDictionary log only quotes keys with "special" characters in them, while JSON quotes everything.  Likewise forward slash is escaped in JSON but not in the NSDictionary log.  Nothing's wrong, so there's nothing to fix.

Comment: mm oke, that seems logic, so the fact that those values are not stored is not related to this difference in display. Tnx!

Comment: @HotLicks: you might want to add this as an answer - this topic might be useful for others from time to time...

Comment: I agreee, @HotLicks you should post your comment as the answer because it's correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're seeing the difference between JSON and an NSLog of an NSDictionary. The NSDictionary log only quotes keys with "special" characters in them, while JSON quotes everything. Likewise forward slash is escaped in JSON but not in the NSDictionary log. Nothing's wrong, so there's nothing to fix.